# URISyntaxException in android

Tags: android

hello i am writing an android application that gets articles from a server , my problem is that i am getting an Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException when i am constructing the URL her is my code

```
public class ArticleActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected static Resources resources;
    // url to make request
    private static URI url = new URI("http://"
            + resources.getString(R.string.SERVER_IP) + ":"
            + resources.getString(R.string.SERVER_PORT)
            + "/qareeboon/requests11/getArticleDetails?uuid="
            + Session.SESSION_UUID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can used following syntax for uri

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com")
```